# How do I create a stealth address using the cli monero wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, stealth-address, new-user

I keep on reading about stealth addresses but am unclear how I would be able to create one using the CLI monero wallet.

Can I generate a stealth address using the wallet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, it is created for you when you send. You don't see stealth addresses directly unless you look at a block explorer. Every new output you send is sent to a new one-time stealth address that the recipient can derive the private key for.